# Как в одном Activity отображать разные Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Допустим у меня есть несколько кнопок в Activity: btn1,btn2 ,btn3,btn4. Как сделать что бы например, при нажатии на btn1 открывалось Activity2 с Fragment 1 , при нажатии на btn2 , тоже открывалось Activity2 с Fragment 1 и Fragment 2, и тд

Comment: а зачем вам куча активностей, можно ведь в контейнере просто пролистывать фрагменты и все, или нужно именно с активностями?

Comment: можно динамически добавлять контейнеры через addView, а в эти контейнеры класть фрагменты.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko только две активности будет , главная в которой будут все кнопки, и вторая где будет информация в зависимости от выбранной кнопки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы уверены что вам нужно именно это, то делайте следующее:

1) По клику по кнопке вызывайте вторую активность передавая значения, зависящие от кнопки

```
@Override
public void onClick(v: View){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    switch(v.id){
        case R.id.button1: 
            intent.putExtra("param", "type1")
            break
        case R.id.button2: 
            intent.putExtra("param", "type2")
            break
    }
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

2) Во второй активити получаете параметр из интента и в заисимости от этого добавляете нужные фрагменты на активити

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    switch(getIntent().getSting("param")){
        case "type1": 
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(Fragment1()).commit();
            break;
        case "type2": 
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(Fragment1()).add(Fragment2()).commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

Но есть подозрение, что ничего страшного не случится, если вместо 2 активити вы сделаете одну, а ваши кнопки положите в еще один фрагмент

Comment: все работает спасибо, как я могу в Activity2 там где case:"type1":getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(Fragment1()).commit(); например спрятать Button который находиться в Fragment1?

Comment: передать состояние фрагменту. Тогда будет так: Fragment 1 f = Fragment1(); f.setParams("type1"); getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(f).commit(); и внутри фрагмента в onViewCreated скрывать кнопку

Comment: где взять f.setParams("type1"); ?

Comment: описать в Fragment1 =)